# Use a variable in one task which is defined in another task in a DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

How to use a variable in one task which is defined in another task in a DevOps pipeline?

This is the yaml script I am using:

```
 -task: PowerShell@2      
       displayName: 'SetVal'     
       inputs:     
         targetType: filePath        
         filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/setval.ps1'     
         pwsh: true     
 -task: PowerShell@2   
       displayName: 'UseVal'  
       inputs:   
         targetType: filePath   
         filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/UseVal.ps1'    
         arguments: -DEFAULT_WORKING_DIRECTORY $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -setvalue  $env:setvalue #setvalue is the variable defined from previous task
```

In the PowerShell script of the first task I have defined the variable to be used in the second task as:

```
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=setvalue;isOutput=true]$setvalue"
```

What change I need to make to use the value in the next task?

Comment: Hi @user10434309, have you checked my suggestions below? When the targetType of PowerShell task is filepath, we can't use macro syntax $(var) directly and we need to use environment variables. To consume the output variables in other stages, we can reference that variable in later stages with the task name and the stageDependencies syntax. See [Set an output variable for use in future stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages) for the detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

check the [devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell)

you can use it by directly calling $(setvalue) in the next task, please check if the $setvalue variable is not $null or empty string

Comment: Now if we want the variable defined in a different stage then what will be the modification that needs to be done to call the variable.

Comment: in that case you can use the variable from earlier stages, check the ms documentation

 $[ stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Answer (score 0):

When you use an output variable in the same job, you don't have to use the `isoutput` property. By default, the variable will be available to downstream steps within the same job. You can use `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=setvalue]$setvalue"` in your setval.ps1.

However, if you do add the `isoutput` property, you'll need to reference the variable with the task name. Please note that the task `name` is the ID of the step and the `displayName` is human-readable name for the task. They are different. In the following example, the second task consumes the variable `setvalue` in the first task "SetVal2" via $(SetVal2.setvalue).

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'SetVal2'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $setvalue = "111"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=setvalue;isOutput=true]$setvalue"

- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'UseVal2' 
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host The value of setvalue is $(SetVal2.setvalue)'
```

---

In your situation, to consume variables defined in other powershell file, we can't use macro syntax `$(var)` directly. When using 'filePath' type script, normally the task would just copy the script file into the working directory of the agent. And then directly execute the script file. It will not pre-parse the macro syntax `$(Var)` in the script file. However, we can pass the value of them via an environment variable in the second task. Refer to the following sample:

The setval.ps1:

```
$setvalue = "abc"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=setvalue]$setvalue"
```

The UseVal.ps1:

```
Write-Host "The value of setvalue is $env:SET_VALUE"
```

The yaml file:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'SetVal'  
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowerShellScripts/setval.ps1'
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'UseVal' 
  env:
    SET_VALUE: $(setvalue)
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowerShellScripts/UseVal.ps1'
```